# UE4 4.26.1 package IOS Arm64 with Assimp

Tags: android, ios, assimp

I'm trying to use Assimp library in UE4 for Android& IOS, right now only successful with Android armeabi-v7a, need some help if anyone already done those kind of things or have those knowledge.
I struggle a lot to compile Assimp to .a&.so, finally it compile successful, but don't know how to translate the .xml for IOS, I think it might need same call "P List" when  do this part, check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urj1j.png)(this is for android& it works).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY9GB.png) is what I met when try to build the Plugin with project, is anyone can help with those issue?

Thanks advances

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know: I have prepared a build environment for this issue. We will deliver this within the next weeks on our github-project.